# Register parameter by name in Unity

Tags: unity-container

With Unity, is it possible to register a parameter by name? My use case is the following. I want to register a value of type DateTime named "asOfDate" such that for any type that has a dependency on DateTime with constructor parameter named "asOfDate", Unity will serve an instance of DateTime equal to the registered value

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible out of the box. Unity does not rely on the parameter name. So when any class expects a DateTime as constructor-parameter then the Unity container will use the registered one, regardless of the parameter name.

To have only certain types injected a special DateTime and others DateTime.Now, you have to register the common DateTime the usual way:

```
container.RegisterType<DateTime>();
```

The special object has be to registered using a name:

```
container.RegisterInstance<DateTime>("special", DateTime.Now);
```

Now when you want to have the special DateTime instance used when resolving an object you can register this object as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyType>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<DateTime>("special"));
```